# Purpose of IborIndex tenor in VanillaSwap

Tags: finance, quantlib

What is the purpose of the IborIndex parameter in VanillaSwap class?

I have been doing some tests with the swapvaluation.cpp and it seems it does not make any difference in the valuation changing it from Euribor6M to, for example, Euribor2W.

I'm sure I'm missing something, but what I understand is that the schedule parametrization for the floating leg is done with floatingSchedule.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I'm right but I think I found the answer to my question.

Looking at the source code of Euribor (https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib/blob/master/ql/indexes/ibor/euribor.cpp) I found that the tenor is used to determine the day convention and the end of month rule used for fixings.

```
BusinessDayConvention euriborConvention(const Period& p) {
        switch (p.units()) {
          case Days:
          case Weeks:
            return Following;
          case Months:
          case Years:
            return ModifiedFollowing;
          default:
            QL_FAIL("invalid time units");
        }
    }

bool euriborEOM(const Period& p) {
        switch (p.units()) {
          case Days:
          case Weeks:
            return false;
          case Months:
          case Years:
            return true;
          default:
            QL_FAIL("invalid time units");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`IborIndex` is a class in QuantLib representing the a finance market index. It is one of the most important class in QuantLib. Unfortunately, the name is confusing. A better name would just be `MarketIndex`.

- Allow all the market index implementation subclasses derived from it. Look at: https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib/tree/9618244fde50546b3ee813dfed76937b01058586/ql/indexes/ibor then you will see what I'm talking about.
- Each index has it's own rules and conventions. For example, the Euribor defines two days for settlement. This is handled in QuantLib. Don't trust me? Let's take a look: https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib/blob/9618244fde50546b3ee813dfed76937b01058586/ql/indexes/ibor/euribor.cpp

> ```
> Euribor365::Euribor365(const Period& tenor,
>                        const Handle<YieldTermStructure>& h)
>      : IborIndex("Euribor365", tenor,
>             2, // settlement days
> ```

- It's just a software abstraction for market index. Nothing more than that.
- Probably the most important function: `Rate forecastFixing(const Date& fixingDate) const;`. This allows us to get a forward rate implied by the market index. **Extremely important** for pricing floating leg in a swap.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I understand that IborIndex is used to get fixing information but I guess what is confusing me is the tenor. If you look to the fixing rates from the generated coupons seems that is using the tenor from the floating schedule, so what is the purpose of the tenor from IborIndex?

Comment: I edited the tittle and try to make my doubt clearer, sorry if my question was confusing